# ngAnimate ngShow Height transition

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying a height animation,

in my html i got

```
<div ng-show="showdiv==true" class="default" ng-animate={show: 'rollup'}>
     This is an error message that can have hell lots of content
</div>

<button ng-click="showdiv=true">Toggle</button>
```

And my css is as follows

```
.rollup{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 5s;
    transition: max-height 5s;
}
```

It seems to be a newbie mistake but i am horrible with css so any pointers to what i can do?

Comment: Why don't you explain what doesn't work?

Comment: In a way it may not be clear indeed, it does not go from 0px to 200px height

Comment: So what does it do instead?

Comment: Nothing it just show as if there is no animation at all

Comment: What is the value on `.default` for `max-height`?

Comment: `.default{ max-height:0px; }` that is the whole class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a few specific things set in order to have working CSS animations. The below code animates opening and closing using just CSS an no reliance on `ng-animate`.

CSS:

```
.default {
  height:0px; 
  background: #e5feff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;

}

.rollup{
  height:200px;
  background: #e5feff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="{'default':!showdiv, 'rollup':showdiv}">
     This is an error message that can have hell lots of content
</div>

<button ng-click="showdiv=!showdiv">Toggle</button>
```

Here is a plunker with a few different examples of vertical animation and triggers. http://plnkr.co/edit/2yS1dDlKxvoccQt5jneB?p=preview

EDIT: I have updated my plunker to better address your question about ng-animate. If you are using angular 1.1.5 or earlier, you can still use ng-animate. As of version 1.2, the ng-animate directive is deprecated. In the plunker update, I have included a few examples of the current usage of angular-animate.